# Whatsapp images shows up in file browser since today

Tags: samsung, whatsapp-messenger

The media folder is hidden in the gallery since I created a `.nomedia`
 file. Since today the `whatsapp` filebrowser started browsing other
 chats as well and shows files from other chats to me.

How can I choose the gallery as the default location for whatsapp media I am about to send OR to hide the media from other chats from the whatsapp file browser?

Comment: `whatsapp filebrowser started browsing other chats` What do you mean by other chats?

Comment: Images I've sent to other whatsapp contacts are shown as entry in a gallery.